# arm linux gnueabi cannot find `-lz`

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I'm, trying to compile a code using arm-linux-gnueabi and cmake. When I'm at the linking phase, I received the following error:
`arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lz`.

This is my linking section at the cmake file:

```
target_link_libraries(myprogram libboost_system.a libboost_thread.a libssl.a libcrypto.a z dl)
```

EDIT: I tried to install the z library using `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` but the error still exists.

Comment: Try `lib32z1-dev` or `libz-dev`. I think the first one worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile it by building it from source using this commands:

```
export CROSS=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
export CC=${CROSS}-gcc
export LD=${CROSS}-ld
./configure --prefix=/home/<your user>/workbench/zlib/final
make
make install
```

I used this [guide](https://how-to-build-for-arm.wikispaces.com/zlib) in order to compile.